# useState hook not updating when adding a variable fetched through ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a variable x whose value I am calculating using a ternary operator. When I try to update this value inside useEffect it does not update it. I understand that setState is async operation and probably it is reading a stale value but is there a way to handle this situation?

```
const [x,setX] = useState();

let val  =data.result. > 900 ? 100 / 5 : data.totalResults / 5
setX(val);
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not update" ? Can you provide some more code so we understand the whole context ? -  it could be that other part of your code is wrong leading to this problem

Comment: Why is there a `.` after `data.result` ? It's syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the value when the value of x is updated. Like the following

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(x)
},[x])
```